# How to remove string sequence within list?

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list:

```
lst = ['object1','object2','object3']
```

how can I go about this to remove the sub-string 'object'?

So if this ran correctly, the output would be:

```
['1','2','3']
```

I tried using the list.remove() method, but it seems to not be able to do this well with a certain sequence of strings.

How could I go about doing this? Is this even possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `[i.replace("object", "") for i in lst]`

Comment: Apparently this is my first day coding because I forgot about replace..... Thank you!

Comment: You might consider accepting one of the answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension with `[x.replace('object', '') for x in lst]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `lambda` for such task.

```
lst = ['object1','object2','object3']

lst = list(map(lambda i: i.replace('object', ''), lst))

print(lst)
```

printed result = `['1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex to remove all non-numeric numbers within a list comprehension

```
import re
lst = ['object1','object2','object3']
output = [re.sub('[^0-9]', '', obj) for obj in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use 'replace' or regex in general, you can try slicing the element of the old list.

Try this:

```
old_list = [ 'Object1', 'Object2', 'Object3']
new_list =  [ i[-1] for i in old_list ]
```

What we are doing above is taking the last element of each of the elements from the old list. The breakdown would look like:

```
old_list = [ 'Object1', 'Object2', 'Object3']
new_list =  []

for i in old_list:
 new_list.append(i[-1])
```